# How to user setdropdown on Spinner

Tags: java, android, eclipse, spinner

I want to costumize only dropdown list on Spinner item but I cant figure out how to apply `adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);` in my code:

```
sp_period_q = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spin_per_q);
sp_period_q.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.spinner_item, Utils.getQuantities()));
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you are doing it with setDropDownViewResource(int layoutResourceId) should work assuming you are also overriding your getDropDownView method.

Calling super.getDropDownView from your overridden method will take care of inflating and passing you back the right layout which you will then set up the way you want.

Something like:

```
@Override
public View getDropDownView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Let super.getDropDownView do the work of inflating and returning
    // to us the right drop down view resource.
    View view = super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);

    // Setup your view here

    return view;
}
```

However, it looks like you are creating another ArrayAdapter at the point when you call setAdapter on your Spinner.

You'll have to create your ArrayAdapter outside of your call to setAdapter and then pass your created adapter to setAdapter.

Comment: Huh all this just to change font color? :( Too much for beginner :)